# Check if Spell Checker is on?

Tags: android, spell-checking

I am using Spell Checker in my Android App. If is is off in the Language and Input settings then the App crashes. It needs to be on for the App to work properly.

Is there a way where before using it I can place a check to verify that is the spell checker is on or turn it on directly from code?

Comment: Do you want to disable the spell correction? if NO, then post the error log

Comment: No i want to check that is it on or off. And also is there a way to turn it on.

Comment: `If it is off in the Language and Input settings then the App crashes.` show crash logcat

Comment: Exception dispatching input event.
Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI(6238): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession.getSuggestions(android.view.textservice.TextInfo, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Means your SpellCheckerSession's object is null. show code.

Comment: I have checked it, I first turn off the SpellChecker and the App crashes. Then I turn on the Spellchecker the App works fine. It is null because the Spellchecker cannot get instantiated beacuse its turned of from the setting menu under language and input. I want to check is it turned on or off.

Comment: simply check if its null or not, before calling getSuggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply check the instance of `SpellCheckerSession` for `null` and accordingly decide whether `Spellchecker` is turned ON or not:

Code Snippet:

```
final TextServicesManager tsm = (TextServicesManager) getSystemService(Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE);

scs = tsm.newSpellCheckerSession(null, null, this, true);

if (scs != null) {
    scs.getSuggestions(new TextInfo(text.getText().toString()), 3);
} else {
    // Show the message to user
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on the spell checker from setting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // You can even open the settings page for user to turn it ON
    ComponentName componentToLaunch = new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.Settings$SpellCheckersSettingsActivity");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(componentToLaunch);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // Error
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ツ